# Screen is black after closing the lid. Still black after reboot

Tags: boot, lubuntu, screen, suspend

Computer: Samsung N150, OS: Lubuntu 14.04, dual boot with windows 7

I am a non-experienced user. I got a black screen after closing the lid, and restarting the computer from the on/off button does NOT work. I get the same black unresponsive screen, although the hard drive is running.

I have tried:

- Plugging in a different monitor
- Some keyboard combinations
- Booting from the USB drive I used when installing Lubuntu

Nothing has worked.

EDIT: called an expert, the graphic card was fried, bought a new computer

Comment: Can you boot into recovery mode from grub bootup screen?

Comment: Grab a copy of Super Grub Disc 2 and boot up from that. It'll find your existing grub installs. Select yours and edit it before booting. Add the following right before `quiet splash`

`acpi_sleep=nonvs`

If your PC is stuck in suspend, this should jog it out.

Answer (score 0):

Could the computer boot from a CD like Super Grub Disc 2 if it was unable to boot from an USB?

I am a non-experienced user too, but this sounds weird. Can it happen? Can you enter the BIOS after switching the computer on? I mean if you are sure that you reach to switch the computer off. Have you tried pressing and holding the on/off button for several seconds in order to force the shut down?

I am sorry in case my bad English sounds rude.

Answer (score -2):

I am using a dell d430 with ubuntu 14.04.  I was having this problem as well.  After some tinkering I found a simple solution for the Dell computer and there should be a similar solution with other laptops as  well.  When I get the black screen after suspend I use the special function key (the key with the Blue Fn on it) and the f7 on the dell this has a blue picture of a monitor on it.  press and hold the fn key and hit the monitor key (f7 in the case of the Dell) and the screen comes back on.  No need to edit scripts or anything else. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please clean the cruft and leave only the answer? Thanks!